# JBoss Weld CDI : Inject the same instance in two different Objects

Tags: java, jboss-weld

I have two basis class `A` and `B`. `B` is injected in `A`. I have a third class `C` injected in `A` and `B`, as follow :

```
class A {
    @Inject B b;
    @Inject C c;
}

class B {
    @Inject C c;
}

class C {

}
```

I'd like the instance of `C` contained in `A` and in `B` is the same. I could use a `setC()` method in `B`, but that's not at all the philosophia of injection. Should I use Weld scopes ? If yes, how should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simply annotate my classes and injections with @Singleton Annotation

```
class A {
    @Inject B b;
    @Inject @Singleton C c;
}

class B {
    @Inject @Singleton C c;
}

@Singleton
class C {

}
```