# Can we share CDI @ApplicationScoped bean instance accross web application in the same EAR?

Tags: java, cdi

I have an JavaEE Application that has 2 web applications. I also have another library web module that contains common_bean that annotated by `@ApplicationScoped`

My question is: Can I share common_bean instance across the two web applications?

**Updated - I did the test**

**In Web App1 (/web1)**

```
@WebServlet("/Servlet1")
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {

@Inject
CommonBean commonBean;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    commonBean.setValue("Servlet1: " + System.currentTimeMillis() + "--" + commonBean);
}
}
```

**In Web App2 (/web2)**

```
@WebServlet("/Servlet2")
public class Servlet2 extends HttpServlet {

@Inject
CommonBean commonBean;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    commonBean.setValue("Servlet2: " + System.currentTimeMillis() + "--" + commonBean);
}
}
```

**The Result**

- If I run /Web1/Servlet1 FIRST then Run /Web2/Servlet2:

  /Web1/Servlet1 ------- Worked

  /Web2/Servlet2 ------- Failed with CDI exception
- If I run /Web2/Servlet2 FIRST then Run /Web1/Servlet1:  ( Restart server then re-test)

  /Web2/Servlet2 ------- Worked

  /Web1/Servlet1 ------- Failed with CDI exception

**Any comments!**

Comment: Yes, move the bean into an own project which is deployed separately and communicate e.g. via REST or RMI.

Comment: @Smutje: I don't want to use REST|RMI. I want to use CDI Inject.

Comment: Have you considered a `@Singleton`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502836/jboss-weld-cdi-inject-the-same-instance-in-two-different-objects

Comment: @Smutje that's not the problem neither the solution.

Comment: How do you have your projects configured and deployed in your application server?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Thank you. I just tried to config Web-lib-module as EAR lib - It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. I like to post the solution here. It may help someone:

**The solution is**: Configure the Web library module as EAR Module Assembly (Lib jar module) - By doing this, only instance of Common bean created and this instance will be shared across all web applications in the same EAR.

I am not sure this is a specification of CDI or NOT but it worked on both Glassfish & Wildfly.

Comment: This seems to be app server specific.  What app server are you deploying to?